# стандартные I\O-потоки

Tags: bat

Что это за надпись дивная вырванная из .bat файла?

```
1<about.txt (set /p l1=<&1 && set /p l2=<&1)
```

Comment: А причем тут ява?

Comment: спешил и не посмотрел метку